# trend line using Dots chart in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, graphael

I have to use g.raphaeljs library to create a scatterplot graph. Not only that but i am trying to get a trend line as well, and am wondering how I should go about this.

I was thinking of calculating the mean of the x axis and the y axis and drawing a straight line based on slope.... but am still stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Also the data used to plot the points on the dot chart is provided by a user.

Comment: I am still looking at how to do this calculation, and basically have come up with nothing what so ever.

Comment: Do you have anything done as yet? Can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: this is a little bit late, but I solved it...